# how to call python from a mutate call?

Tags: python, r, reticulate

Consider this simple example

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reticulate)

tibble(text = 'hasta la vista baby') %>% 
  mutate(processed = purrr::map(text, ~my_python_func(.x)))
```

I am trying to call and apply a python function in the `dplyr::mutate()` call. Is this possible with `reticulate`? I was not able to make this run. The simple python function is shown below

```
### python file.py

def my_python_func(mystring):
  return mystring.split(' ')
```

What do you think?
Thanks!

Comment: when you say "Not able to make this run" what do you mean? Did you hit an error?

Comment: yes, I am not sure how to use reticulate in this context

Comment: would you mind to show the error message? Additionally, what happens if you call it for one string?

Comment: there is no error message, I do not know what is the correct syntax

Comment: Try doing this in R, it has an inbuilt `strsplit()` function.